# TouchID and RevealViewController

Tags: swift3, swrevealviewcontroller, touch-id

I am using the SWRevealViewController and everything was working perfectly, I added LocalAuthentication so a user could validate their login with Touch ID.

Now the RevealViewController doesnt not do anything when you use Touch ID, if I cancel the Touch ID everything works perfectly..

I havnt posted any code and was just wondering if anyone have experienced anything similar and knew the solution..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have worked out that the LAContext() polices did not finishing running properly before I moved to a new ViewController which stopped the RevealViewController from working. I cant however figure out how to only move to the ViewController once the LAContext policies finish completely. When I try it seems to be happening in sync and so it tries to move before the polices finish..

anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this by adding

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
```

after looking for evaluatePolicy success